# sql query - sql where clause using multiple criteria in where clause

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am new to VBA. My database is Ms-access. I wrote the query to extract the data from database based on four criteria.

**My Database:**

```
KeyerName    Job   score  date      time
xxx           1     50    12/14/13  02:30
yyy           1     60    01/02/14  12:00
xxx           4     75    02/08/14  08:00  
xxx           4     50    02/08/14  08:00  
yyy           1     90    01/02/14  12:00
```

I want to extract my data as sum of score based on the date, time , job and keyername

I wrote the sql query as,

```
ssql= "select sum(score) from typt where Keyername='XXX', Job ='4', date=#02/08/14#, time= '08:00'"
```

However i have received the error. 
My output would be:

```
score  
 125
```

Can anyone suggest me how to use the multiple criteria in where clause sql?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace each of your commas with AND:

```
select sum(score) from typt where Keyername='XXX' AND Job ='4' AND ...
```

Comment: Hi thank for your reply, I tried the and also. But it returns the error" object dosen't support property or method". How can I use the multiple criteria..

Comment: I guess we need to see more code. All you provided is the string in which you form your query. Clearly you've got something else that's failing. Also - debugging tip - Strip your code out to the simplest piece you can and see if that works. Example - drop the 'where' clause altogether and see if you get a sum of all the scores. Then add critieria back one at a time